# Writing a pencode and I am trying to link buttons to a countdown timer for start and reset

Tags: javascript

I am in the process of writing a pencode https://codepen.io/Jonbeckner/pen/XWqOvrp
I copied a codepen countdown timer to my existing work. I got it to run when you click the start button. I now need it to reset the time when the reset button is clicked. My code to start the timer is as follows

```
document.querySelector('.button-start').addEventListener('click', function() 
{ 
     startTimer();
});
```

I also set a variable to check if the timer is running so it won't execute multiple times.

My ask is as follows: How would I get it to reset using the reset button? Thanks for putting up with my questions as I learn JS.

Comment: Add an `eventListener` that listens for when the reset button is clicked, then stop the timer by clearing the `setInterval` function for it, then resetting `timeLeft` and `timePassed` back to `TIME_LIMIT` and `null`, as well as resetting the animated timer itself.

Comment: I added the eventListener but am unsure as to how to clear setInterval

Comment: The `id` of a `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` function is assigned to whatever variable the function is, so in this case `timerInterval`, if in the global scope, would have its value set at the `id` of the function. You can use `clearInterval(timeInterval)` or however you access it to clear the interval in that function.

Comment: document
 .querySelector(".button-start-reset")
 .addEventListener("click", function () {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
  timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
  timerInterval = null;
  isRunning = false;
 });

This code will stop the timer but I'm lost as to what to do to reset. I'm an extremely new js programmer and need lots of help.

Comment: Whatever you did should have worked, as the time is 100% reset, and perhaps if you try to start it again it will work?

Comment: Nothing but stop the timer. I just tried it.

Comment: Look at the answer to this question and try that out instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It speeds up because another countdown gets layered on every time the button is clicked, so it decrements that many times faster. You could disable the button at the start of `startTimer` :

```js
function startTimer() {
    //disable start-timer button 
    document.querySelector(".button-start").disabled = true;

    // rest of the function [below] is copied from the fiddle
    timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
        timePassed = timePassed += 1;
        timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
        document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(timeLeft);
        setCircleDasharray();
        setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

        if (timeLeft === 0) { onTimesUp(); }
    }, 1000);
}
```

To make the reset button work, you just need to define a reset function and then add an event listener [to the reset button] to call the function from:

```js
//adding click event listener
document.querySelector(".button-start-reset").addEventListener("click", function(){resetTimer();});

//function definition
function resetTimer() {
    onTimesUp(); 
    const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
    timePassed = 0;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(timeLeft);
    setCircleDasharray();
    document.getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining").classList.remove(warning.color);
    document.getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining").classList.remove(alert.color);
    document.getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining").classList.add(info.color);

    //enable start-timer button again
    document.querySelector(".button-start").disabled = false;
}
```

---

---

Also, [if you wanted] you could **remove the disable/enable lines** from the functions above and instead set the start-timer button's click event handler to toggle it between start and pause:

```js
var timerRunning = false; // flag variable

document.querySelector(".button-start").addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (timerRunning) {
        timerRunning = false;
        this.innerText = 'Start Timer';
        onTimesUp(); 
    } else {
        timerRunning = true;
        this.innerText = 'Pause Timer';
        startTimer();
    }
});
```

and then the `onTimesUp` function would need to be edited to

```js
function onTimesUp() {
    clearInterval(timerInterval); 
    document.querySelector(".button-start").innerText = 'Start Timer';
    timerRunning = false;
}
```